# Point cloud to a mesh in Point Cloud Library

Tags: c++, point-clouds, point-cloud-library

Is there a function/class in PCL that converts a point cloud to a mesh?

Comment: did you check the documentation on the website? It states that there are algorithms for surface reconstruction. See [this](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/group__surface.html) for example.

Comment: There are classes that construct Convex Hulls and Alpha-Hulls: `pcl::ConcaveHull` and `pcl::ConvexHull`.